# Is it provable from Zermelo–Fraenkel Set Theory, that if a countable set of sets exists, then this other countable set of sets exists?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, first-order-logic

[Zermelo–Fraenkel Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) is a system of axioms for describing set theory.

Suppose we assume the following:

> For some set $B$ there exists a function $f_{1}$ subset of $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(B))$ such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ $f_{1}(k)$ is a non-empty subset of $B$.
> $\mathcal{P}(B)$ denotes the "power set" of $B$.

[image: countable set of non-empty sets]

Can we then show that the following also exists?

$f_{2} = \{ (k, T)  \text{ such that } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } T =  \{ (k, x): x \in f_{1}(k) \} \}$

Notice that we are not enumerating the elements of $f_{1}(k)$
The sets in question are not necessarily countable.
The numbering scheme for $f_{1}(k)$ is $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...$ not $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...$

[image: new function with elements pseudo-numbered]

#### BEGIN FORMAL CONJECTURE

> If, for some set $B$, there exists a function $f_{1}$ subset of $(\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(B))$ such that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_{1}(k)$ is a non-empty subset of $B$ then if $f_{2} = \{ (k, T)  \text{ such that } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } T =  \{ (k, x): x \in f_{1}(k) \} \}$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, f_{2}(k) = \{ (k, x): x \in f_{1}(k) \}$ then all of the following are true:
>
> - $f_{2}$ is well-defined
> - $f_{2}$ exists
> - $f_{2}$ is a function.

Note that $f_{2}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N} \times (\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(B))$, so, we must also have $\mathbb{N} \times (\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{P}(B))$ exists or is well-defined.

By "function" we mean that:

> for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $b \in B$ such that $(k, b) \in f$
> and
> for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all $b1, b2 \in B$ if $(k, b1) \in f$ and $(k, b2) \in f$ then $b1 = b2$

My question is, "Is my conjecture provable using only Zermelo–Fraenkel Set Theory (***ZF***) and basic logic?" The conjecture is obviously true, but is it provable in ***ZF***?

#### END FORMAL CONJECTURE

#### BEGIN INFORMAL, INTUITIVE, SLOPPY, CONJECTURE

> If we have a bunch of sets, $S(1), S(2), S(3)$, etc..., then we can make some new sets $T(1), T(2), T(3), ...$ with a very simple change: we take all of the elements of $S(1)$ and prefix them with the number $1$. For example,
>
> - If "apple" was a set of $S(1)$ then $(1, ``\text{apple}")$ is an element of $T(1)$
> - If $y$ was an element of set $S(2)$ then $(2, y)$ is an element of $T(2)$.
> - If $z$ was an element of set $S(3)$ then $(3, z)$ is an element of $T(3)$.

#### END INFORMAL, INTUITIVE, SLOPPY, CONJECTURE

Comment: No; see the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289709/choice-function-for-collection-of-arbitrary-finite-sets-ac-required). (And your $f_2$ is a subset of $\Bbb N\times B$, not $\Bbb N\times(\Bbb N\times B)$.)

Comment: Your conjecture is obviously false, not obviously true.  If $f_1(k)$ has more than one element for some $k$, then $f_2$ is not a function because more than one pair of the form $(k,x)$ is in $f_2$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I made a mistake in my definition of $f_{2}$ I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

As it is now written, $f_2$ is functional; it's also injective. It obviously exists since it's a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\times B)$, which exists for any $B$; it's not clear what you mean by "well-defined", but if you mean whether there's such a thing as $f_2(k)$ for any $k$, then the answer is yes, regardless of whether $f_1(k)$ is non-empty or even defined.

First, functionality.

To see why it's functional, suppose that we had $(k,T)$ and $(k,S)$ both in $f_2$. Then by the definition of $f_2$, $T=\{(k,x)\;|\; x\in f_1(k)\}$; also by the definition of $f_2$, $S$ is the exact same set. That's really it, there's nothing else to prove.

To see that it's injective, suppose $f_2(k)=f_2(j)$. Then $$\{(k,x)\;|\;x\in f_1(k)\}\subseteq\{(j,y)\;|\;y\in f_1(j)\}$$ and vice versa. Since both are non-empty by our assumption on $f_1$, there is a $(k,x)$ that is identical to $(j,y)$ for some $y$; but then $k=j$. Hence injective.

To understand why it's defined, let's look at $T=\{(k,x)\;|\; x\in f_1(k)\}$ a little more closely. If $f_1(k)$ is defined and empty, then $T$ is simply empty; there are no pairs satisfying its defining condition. What if $f_1$ isn't defined at $k$? Just by expanding out definitions, one can see that $$T=\{(k,x)\;|\; \exists A((k,A)\in f_1\wedge x\in A)\}.$$ Given our assumption that $f_1$ isn't defined at $k$ (i.e. that no pair $(k,A)$ is in $f_1$), $T$ is simply empty again. So worst case scenario here is that $f_2=\mathbb{N}\times\{\varnothing\}$, which is indeed a function.

**TL;DR, At no point is Choice even a useful axiom to apply, much less a necessary one.**

By the way, you somewhat puzzlingly say the following in your conjecture:

> . . . if $f_{2} = \{ (k, T)  \text{ such that } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } T =  \{ (k, x): x \in f_{1}(k) \} \}$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, f_{2}(k) = \{ (k, x): x \in f_{1}(k) \}$ then . . .

The second part of this conjunction either begs the question of why you're writing a functional expression if you don't know if $f_2$ is a function, or it's entirely redundant because that's just what $f_2$'s definition already says in the first conjunct.