# Without AC, is the statement "the union of countably many countable sets is countable" still true?

Tags: set-theory

I've realized that there are many results in set theory rely on the theorem that states *"the union of countably many countable sets is countable"*. However, all of the proofs of this theorem I've found so far, including ones on SE, rely on the axiom of choice.

So, I'm wonder without AC is it still true or false or neither provable nor refutable?

Comment: Related? Duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1935724/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1289709/42969.

Comment: @MartinR, correct me if I'm wrong but that's a different question asking for why it's needed in the proof right? Here I'm asking if it can be proven/rejected (or either) without AC.

Comment: You can do it [with countable choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice#Overview), but even that is slightly stronger in $\mathsf{ZF}$ than the desired result.

Comment: If you are asking "is it needed", then the answer is one word. Yes. If that is a satisfactory answer, then surely "Yes, and here's why" or even "Yes, here's why, so in these cases you don't need it" is even better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's independent of ZF; more specifically it's known that it's consistent with ZF that $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100717/zf-the-reals-are-the-countable-union-of-countable-sets-consistent).

However, most of the time in practice a slightly different statement can be used, namely that a *counted* union of *counted* sets is *counted*, where a "counted set" is a set equipped with a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$ (rather than just a set such that there exists such a bijection). This saves you from having to choose bijections and you can just use the given bijections to explicitly construct the desired bijection; this is provable in ZF.

Comment: How would the outline of the proof look, then? I could construct such a bijection if the sets in question are disjoint, but what if they aren't? Then the usual proof only gives us a surjection, and from there I would use that the existence of surjections in both directions imply the existence of a bijection, but that requires choice. How does one sidestep this issue?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: whatever argument you know that explicitly constructs a bijection in the disjoint case (which reduces to showing that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable), perform the same construction but just skip any elements that have already appeared.

Answer (score -3):

You have sets numbered 1,2,3,4, etc.

Each set has elements numbered 1,2,3,4 etc.

For each element of the union you calculate its set number plus its index in the set. Then you enumerate the one element with sum 2, the two elements with sum 3, the three elements with sum 4, and so on.

(You need to handle duplicates yourself).

Comment: To index the elements 1,2,3,4..., in the countably infinitely many sets, don't you already need the Axiom of Choice? You are explicitly choosing one element of each set to be labelled 1, etc.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That's not actually the issue, since countability guarantees the existence of a counting function. So choosing an element to be labeled 1, 2, etc. is fine. The "choice" function is given by countability, not by AC. However, you need to choose a counting function for every set (for each set there is a non-empty set of counting functions, of which we need to choose one for every set). That's where AC would usually come in.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Furthermore, if the sets only contain natural numbers, then there is a canonical choice of counting function (the function listing them in increasing order) and AC is not needed.