# countably finite set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If I have a set that is the union of 10 finite sets, is the set countable? The 10 finite sets are sets made from the intersection of a line and a circle
 As seen below ,
{ { (x,y) E R^2 | x^2 + y^2 = z^2 }  n  { (x,y) E R^2 | y^2 -x^4 = 0 } } .
z holds the value 1.

Comment: OK, I'll bite.  How can the union of a finite number of finite sets, being finite itself, be uncountable?

Comment: okay yes so it has to be countable. In relation to proving it? can I just state the fact there is a finite number of sets that are finite

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408636/when-an-infinite-union-of-countable-sets-is-uncountable

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

A union of a finite number of finite sets is finite, so yes it is countable.

Comment: Would that stand for a justification for the answer?

Comment: That depends on the context. Are you being asked to *prove* that a finite union of finite sets is finite? If so, then you would need a more explicit justification. If you just want to use the fact that a finite union of finite sets is finite, then nobody is going to question that fact without justification.

Comment: I've to state whether the set is finite, countably infinite, or uncountably infinite? and justify my answer.

Comment: I can't really tell you what your instructor is expecting, but it wouldn't take long to write down a justification of this fact.